# SelectList не отображается на .cshtml из-за ошибки конвертации

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp, asp-net-core-mvc

Есть объекты сущности:

```
[Table("friend")]
    public partial class Friend
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id_Friend")]
        public long IdFriend { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указана фамилия")]
        [DisplayName("Фамилия")]
        [Column("Family_name", TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указано имя")]
        [DisplayName("Имя")]
        [Column("Name_", TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Отчество")]
        [Column("Patronymic_name", TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string PatronymicName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Дата рожд.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указана дата рождения")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Column("Date_birth", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? DateBirth { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указан насел. п-т")]
        [DisplayName("Насел. пункт")]
        [Column("City_id")]
        public int? CityId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Округ")]
        [Column("District_id")]
        public int? DistrictId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указана улица")]
        [DisplayName("Улица")]
        [Column("Street_id")]
        public int? StreetId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Микрорайон")]
        [Column("MicroDistrict_id")]
        public int? MicroDistrictId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указан дом")]
        [DisplayName("Дом")]
        [Column("House_id")]
        public int? HouseId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Строение")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(10)")]
        public string Building { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Квартира")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(10)")]
        public string Apartment { get; set; }
        [MinLength(11)]
        [MaxLength(12)]
        [RegularExpression(@"[+]?[0-9]+"), StringLength(12)]
        [DisplayName("Тел. избирателя")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(12)")]
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Организация")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string Organization { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Сфера деят-ти")]
        [Column("FieldActivity_id")]
        public int? FieldActivityId { get; set; }
        [MinLength(11)]
        [MaxLength(12)]
        [RegularExpression(@"[+]?[0-9]+"), StringLength(12)]
        [DisplayName("Тел. ответств-го")]
        [Column("Phone_number_responsible", TypeName = "varchar(12)")]
        public string PhoneNumberResponsible { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Адресс")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(500)")]
        public string Adress { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("QRcode")]
        [Column("QRcode", TypeName = "varchar(4500)")]
        public string Qrcode { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Примечание")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Агитатор")]
        [Column("User_id")]
        public long? UserId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Группа")]
        [Column("GroupU_id")]
        public int? GroupUId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Населен. п-т")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(CityId))]
        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public virtual City City { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Округ")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(DistrictId))]
        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public virtual District District { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Сфера деят-ти")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(FieldActivityId))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Fieldactivity.Friends))]
        public virtual Fieldactivity FieldActivity { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Группа")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(GroupUId))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Groupu.Friends))]
        public virtual Groupu GroupU { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Дом")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(HouseId))]
        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public virtual House House { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Микрорайон")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(MicroDistrictId))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Microdistrict.Friends))]
        public virtual Microdistrict MicroDistrict { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Улица")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(StreetId))]
        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public virtual Street Street { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }

[Table("user")]
    public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            Friends = new HashSet<Friend>();
            Groupsusers = new HashSet<Groupsusers>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("Id_User")]
        public long IdUser { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Пользователь")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указано имя")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указан пароль")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Роль")]
        [Column("Role_id")]
        public int? RoleId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Фамилия")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указана фамилия")]
        [Column("Family_name", TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Имя")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указано имя")]
        [Column("Name_", TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Отчество")]
        [Column("Patronymic_name", TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string PatronymicName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Дата рождения")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Column("Date_birth", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? DateBirth { get; set; }
        [MinLength(11)]
        [MaxLength(12)]
        [RegularExpression(@"[+]?[0-9]+"), StringLength(12)]
        [DisplayName("Телефон")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(12)")]
        public string Telephone { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Роль")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(RoleId))]
        [InverseProperty("Users")]
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Друзья")]
        [InverseProperty("User")]
        public virtual ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Группы")]
        [InverseProperty("User")]
        public virtual ICollection<Groupsusers> Groupsusers { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Кол-во избирателей")]
        [NotMapped]
        public string numberFriends { get; set; }

    }
```

На странице на которой происходит правка объекта, есть следующее поле для отображения списка объектов User:

```
...
    <div class="form-group">
                <select asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.UserId"></select>
            </div>
...
```

И в этой строке при вызове данной страницы выдает ошибку:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'
```

Контроллер возвращающий контент для представления:

```
Authorize(Roles = "admin, user")]
    public class FriendsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<FriendsController> _logger;
        private readonly VoterCollectorContext _context;

        public FriendsController(VoterCollectorContext context, ILogger<FriendsController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var friend = await _context.Friend.FindAsync(id);
            if (friend == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            ViewData["CityId"] = new SelectList(_context.City, "IdCity", "Name", friend.CityId);
            ViewData["DistrictId"] = new SelectList(_context.District, "IdDistrict", "Name", friend.DistrictId);
            ViewData["FieldActivityId"] = new SelectList(_context.Fieldactivity, "IdFieldActivity", "Name", friend.FieldActivityId);
            ViewData["GroupUId"] = new SelectList(_context.Groupu, "IdGroup", "Name", friend.GroupUId);
            ViewData["HouseId"] = new SelectList(_context.House, "IdHouse", "Name", friend.HouseId);
            ViewData["MicroDistrictId"] = new SelectList(_context.Microdistrict, "IdMicroDistrict", "Name", friend.MicroDistrictId);
            ViewData["PollingStationId"] = new SelectList(_context.PollingStation, "IdPollingStation", "Name", friend.PollingStationId);
            var selectLists= new SelectList(_context.Street, "IdStreet", "Name", friend.StreetId);
            ViewData["StreetId"] = new SelectList(_context.Street, "IdStreet", "Name", friend.StreetId);
            var selectListUsers = new SelectList(_context.User, "IdUser", "FamilyName", friend.UserId);
            ViewData["UserId"] = selectListUsers;
            return View(friend);
        }
}
```

Если посмотреть через отладчик, что возвращает контроллер для этого списка, то он не пустой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробное описание ошибки:

> MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetString(int ordinal) in Row.cs
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetString(int ordinal) in
> MySqlDataReader.cs lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader
> , ResultContext , int[] , ResultCoordinator )
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable+Enumerator.MoveNext()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetListItemsWithValueField()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetListItems()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetEnumerator()
> System.Collections.Generic.List..ctor(IEnumerable collection)
> System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable source)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.DefaultHtmlGenerator.GenerateGroupsAndOptions(string
> optionLabel, IEnumerable selectList,
> ICollection currentValues)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.DefaultHtmlGenerator.GenerateSelect(ViewContext
> viewContext, ModelExplorer modelExplorer, string optionLabel, string
> expression, IEnumerable selectList,
> ICollection currentValues, bool allowMultiple, object
> htmlAttributes)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.SelectTagHelper.Process(TagHelperContext
> context, TagHelperOutput output)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext
> context, TagHelperOutput output)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.RunAsync(TagHelperExecutionContext
> executionContext)
> AspNetCore.Views_Friends_Edit.b__23_0() in Edit.cshtml
> +
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.GetChildContentAsync(bool
> useCachedResult, HtmlEncoder encoder)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext
> context, TagHelperOutput output)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.g__Awaited|0_0(Task
> task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, int i, int count)
> AspNetCore.Views_Friends_Edit.ExecuteAsync() in Edit.cshtml
> +
> ViewData["Title"] = "Edit"; Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage
> page, ViewContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage
> page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
> viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
> viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData,
> ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable
> statusCode)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> context, ViewResult result)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter,
> TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next,
> Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter,
> TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref
> bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State
> next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.    at
> MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetString(Int32 ordinal) in
> /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/Row.cs:line 377    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 ordinal) in
> /*/src/MySqlConnector/MySql.Data.MySqlClient/MySqlDataReader.cs:line
> 272    at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader ,
> ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetListItemsWithValueField() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetListItems()   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetEnumerator()  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.DefaultHtmlGenerator.GenerateGroupsAndOptions(String
> optionLabel, IEnumerable`1 selectList, ICollection`1 currentValues)
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.DefaultHtmlGenerator.GenerateSelect(ViewContext
> viewContext, ModelExplorer modelExplorer, String optionLabel, String
> expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList, ICollection`1 currentValues,
> Boolean allowMultiple, Object htmlAttributes)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.SelectTagHelper.Process(TagHelperContext
> context, TagHelperOutput output)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext
> context, TagHelperOutput output)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.RunAsync(TagHelperExecutionContext
> executionContext)    at
> AspNetCore.Views_Friends_Edit.b__23_0() in
> D:\My_PROGRAMS\voteCollector\Views\Friends\Edit.cshtml:line 123    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.GetChildContentAsync(Boolean
> useCachedResult, HtmlEncoder encoder)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext
> context, TagHelperOutput output)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.g__Awaited|0_0(Task
> task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, Int32 i, Int32
> count)    at AspNetCore.Views_Friends_Edit.ExecuteAsync() in
> D:\My_PROGRAMS\voteCollector\Views\Friends\Edit.cshtml:line 4    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage
> page, ViewContext context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage
> page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
> viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData,
> ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1
> statusCode)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> context, ViewResult result)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Comment: То, что список непустой - ещё не значит, что в одном из элементов есть свойство установленное в NULL. У вас 11 selectList'ов -- вы могли бы не вываливать на нас все, а сократить минимальный пример до одного конкретного листа, в котором данные некорректны -- понять проблему, а поняв исправить сначала в одном листе, а потом по аналогии и в остальных.

Comment: @AK, не понял вас, скажите, что нужно проверить?

Comment: Судя по всему у вас у одного из User'ов в поле Фамилия (FamilyName) стоит null, тут и происходит падение.

Comment: @AK, у меня ошибка только на 1-ом selectList'е, на остальных все работает норм

Comment: Ага, о том я и говорю: ошибка только в одном, но вы зачем-то вывалили на нас кучу кода, не имеющего отношения к вопросу. Зачем? Чем труднее понять вопрос - тем меньше хочется на него отвечать, вы сами уменьшаете шансы получить ответ через ru so.

Comment: @AK, да есть такой User, у которого фамилия не заполнена, соответственно null. Можно как-то обработать этот вариант?

Comment: Очевидно, вам нужно заменить null на пустую строку - и проблема решится сама собой. Ну хотя бы что-то в духе: `new SelectList(_context.User.Select(x => new {IdUser = x.IdUser, FamilyName = x.FamilyName ?? string.Empty } ), "IdUser", "FamilyName", friend.UserId);`

Comment: @AK, попробовал ```  ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.User.Select(x =>
            new { IdUser = x.IdUser, UserName = x.UserName, Password = x.Password,
                RoleId = x.RoleId, FamilyName = x.FamilyName ?? string.Empty, Name = x.Name ?? string.Empty, PatronymicName = x.PatronymicName ?? string.Empty,
                DateBirth = x.DateBirth, Telephone = x.Telephone, Role = x.Role, Friends = x.Friends,  Groupsusers = x.Groupsusers, numberFriends = x.numberFriends}), "IdUser", "FamilyName", friend.UserId);
``` -  ошибка осталась

Comment: @AK, попробовал выводить поле "UserId" - оно всегда заполнено, но ошибка осталась по прежнему. Ведать есть ещё какая-то причина

Comment: @AK, вы были правы дело в полях со значением "null"  + в аннотации ```[Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указана фамилия")]```. Создание нового объекта с перезаписью свойств не помогает. Тут наверное либо убирать данную аннотацию , либо заполнять поля в ручную. Если вас есть другой способ, то напишите

Comment: Это совершенно другой вопрос уже - как заставить аннотации действовать. Текущий вопрос -- как вывести данные из базы содержащие null. Показанного кода хватило только на ответ на текущий вопрос, хотите новый вопрос - создавайте новый. Пока что в рамках комментария могу подкинуть только один направляющий на верный путь вопрос: в какой момент должны сработать аннотации - при получении данных из веб-формы в контроллер (и что обеспечивает запуск аннотаций) или в момент чтения из базы?

Comment: @AK, тогда оформите в ответ про null, я отмечу

Comment: Уступаю это вам -- такие подробности вам лучше видно и получится лучше указать в ответе.